# Verfiying satisfiability of formulas

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I have this question

[image: Question]

And was wondering if someone could help improve my answer (I am learning English):

a) satisfiable as long P=True, Q=True, R= True. Then (P^Q^R) will be true. Also, (not P or R) will be (False or True), which is True. Then, True and True is True. So, (P and Q and R) and (not P or R) is also true.

b) not. P=True, Q=True, R=True, so not P is false, not R is false. Not P or not R is false. True and False is False. cannot find a true

c) will work as long as (if P then Q) is false and (if not P then not Q) is true, does not happen. so can be satisfiable

Comment: Please comment if the homework is supposed to be in English.

Comment: Yes my English is not very good  ;(

Comment: Ok, let me recommend capitalizing your sentences and not forgetting periods '.'.  Your teachers will appreciate it.  It makes you more likely to get good responses here too.  Without basic things like that, it looks like you aren't trying, and people will assume that you don't care about your own question.  Anyway I posted an answer, please check it.

Comment: +1 To this question for being available to provide feedback and editing your question appropriately.  I appreciate questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation for **(c)** is wrong.

$$A \rightarrow B$$ is satisfiable as long as you don't have both $A = \text{true}$ and $B = \text{false}$.  Your answer says that the unsatisfied case is $A = \text{false}$ and $B = \text{true}$, which is incorrect.

In your formula
$$\underbrace{(P \rightarrow Q)}_A \rightarrow \underbrace{(\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q)}_B$$

it is possible to create $A = \text{true}$ and $B= \text{false}$.  This is the case of $P = \text{false}$ and $Q = \text{true}$.  Therefore your claim that **(c)** is a tautology is incorrect.

---

> a) satisfiable as long P=True, Q=True, R= True. Then (P^Q^R) will be true. Also, (not P or R) will be (False or True), which is True. Then, True and True is True. So, (P and Q and R) and (not P or R) is also true.

Correct, but hard to read.  Here is my suggestion:

- Both $(P \land Q \land R)$ and $(\lnot Q \lor R)$ must be true.
- $(P \land Q \land R)$ requires that $P=\text{true}$, $Q=\text{true}$, and $R=\text{true}$.
- That assignment makes $(\lnot Q \lor R)$ true, so it satisfies **(a)**.

> b) not. P=True, Q=True, R=True, so not P is false, not R is false. Not P or not R is false. True and False is False. cannot find a true

Again correct, but hard to read.  Here is my suggestion.

- Both $(P \land Q \land R)$ and $(\lnot Q \lor \lnot R)$ must be true.
- $(P \land Q \land R)$ requires that $P=\text{true}$, $Q=\text{true}$, and $R=\text{true}$.
- That assignment makes $(\lnot Q \lor \lnot R)$ false, so nothing satisfies **(b)**.

Comment: So is my English ok for my first two answers is it understandable?

Comment: You could be more organized.  I'll edit my post to make a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have learnt English recently it is very helpful.

Comment: @Maus_ I appreciate you learning English.  If you add to your post that "I am learning English", it helps us to know how to help you.  Many people know English, but have mistakes in their post because they are lazy, so we ignore them.  When you add "I am learning", we won't ignore you then.  I hope this helps.